SPSS Files Won't Save At Location
While working with SPSS for the first time I've encountered this issue while trying to edit a ".sav" file.
The editing itself goes along just fine, but when trying to save the changes an error occurs that claims that I can't save the file to that location since it already has a file of that name (the file I started working on in the first place):

The specified file or directory cannot be written to because it is read-only or does not exist.
Save the file with another name or to a different location or change the access permissions first.

As I have met similar situations using excel and word I can't tell if this issue is an SPSS thing or a more general thing.
Closing the file and opening did not do anything...
